# Run-time error: '-2147417848 (80010108)' in macro

Tags: excel, vba

If I enter a word with a space in column A (for example: `L3` , `FMA` , `Nest` , etc.), then it gives an error: "Run-time error: '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'HorizontalAlignment' of object'Range' failed". How can I fix this?

I have this macro:

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rng As Range, v As Variant
    For Each rng In Target
        v = Split(rng, " ")
        If UBound(v) <> 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Right(rng, 1) <> "m" Then
            rng = v(1) & " " & v(0)
     NumberFormat = "@"
      With Target
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With Target.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
    End With
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This macro converts the data to **(any number)m** and **(any number)M** be on the right.

For example:

```
L3 280M
500m FMA
Nest 475m
340m Pr6
720M uT10
etc.
```

Convert to:

```
L3 280M
FMA 500m
Nest 475m
Pr6 340m
uT10 720M
etc.
```

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` You are entering an infinite loop. The values with "m" at the end don't trigger the change event or anything without exactly one space.

Comment: @Warcupine How can I do this? I tried to paste `Application.EnableEvents = False`  after `If Right(rng, 1) <> "m" Then`. And `Application.EnableEvents = True` after  `.Size = 11
    End With`. But the error appears again. Could you send me the complete code or a piece of code where this should be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues with this macro.

First, as Warcupine pointed out, you definitely need to suspend events while this code runs. Your changing the worksheet contents so without suspending events you would get numerous recursive calls for every change. This was the cause of the original error for this question.

Second, if there are leading spaces or more than one internal space then the v array won't have the values at index 0 and 1. A simple fix to this is to use the worksheet trim function. The VBA trim function only removes leading and trailing spaces but the worksheet function also removes additional internal spaces too.

Third, jumping to cleanexit stops processing any remaining cells in the target.

Also, you're formatting the entire target every time instead of just the active rng cell, you ignore upper case 'M' and cells where the text term ends in 'm'. You only format those cells that need flipping.

One remaining issue with the following code is that it will flip any cell with two terms that ends in 'M'.

Here is the test range that I used:

L3 280M
500m FMA
One 567m Three
Nest 475m
340m Pr6
The Tram
720M uT10
345m RLM

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim numberformat As String
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim rng As Range, v As Variant
    For Each rng In Target
        'Worksheet Trim removes leading and trailing spaces and additional internal spaces
        rng = WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng)
        v = Split(rng, " ")
        'Skip any cell with more than two terms but still process remaining targets
        If UBound(v) = 1 Then
            If Len(v(0)) = 4 And IsNumeric(Left(v(0), 3)) And UCase(Right(v(0), 1)) = "M" Then
                rng = Trim(v(1) & " " & v(0))
            End If
            With rng
                .numberformat = "@"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With rng.Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Size = 11
            End With
        End If
    Next rng

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is what I wanted! Now I noticed another problem, that if enter or paste the words `The Tram`, and then click on this cell 2 times, then the letters are reversed and get `Tram The`. For example: same thing happens with `333 nits` letters change to `nits 333`, etc. How to fix it??

Comment: Instead of checking for what the right term isn't, test if the left term is what you expect. Replace the "IF Ucase" thru "Else If" lines with: `If Len(v(0)) = 4 And IsNumeric(Left(v(0), 3)) And UCase(Right(v(0), 1)) = "M" Then` You've already eliminated any cell with more than two terms, this will verify the left term has four characters begining with 3 numbers and ending with the letter 'M' and flip it from the left term to the right.

Comment: Could you send me the full code how to do it. Please.

Comment: I updated my earlier answer to include this change.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you one more question? Now I noticed that if enter `oct20`, then the conversion to `44854`. If enter `aug21`, then the conversion to `44794`. How can fix it?

Comment: What you're seeing is the numeric value Excel uses to store dates. The cells are formatted with the "General" format. Change the format for those cells to "Custom" using the date format of "mmmdd" if you want the date shown as "Oct20". Search help on Date format codes for all the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Understood. I moved `.numberformat = "@"` to `For Each rng In Target With rng .numberformat = "@" End With`. Now it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you use Worksheet Change you need to disable the events or your event triggers itself causing an infinite loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim numberformat As String
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim rng As Range, v As Variant
    For Each rng In Target
        v = Split(rng, " ")
        If UBound(v) <> 1 Then GoTo cleanexit
        If Right(rng, 1) <> "m" Then
            rng = trim(v(1) & " " & v(0))
            numberformat = "@"
            With Target
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With Target.Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Size = 11
            End With
        End If
    Next rng
cleanexit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I noticed that if enter a word with a space `L3 `, then when click on the cell where the word was entered, "jumps" occur. First, the word `L3 ` has a space in the cell, then if click on the cell again, it becomes without a space. How to fix it?

Comment: modified the `rng = ` line

Comment: It is working. But if enter two or more spaces, then the problem comes back again.

Comment: If you enter two or more spaces it never runs, by design `If UBound(v) <> 1 Then GoTo cleanexit`

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, we are pretty far off from the scope of the question at this point and I'm unsure of what all the possible variations you might have are and how you want to handle them.

Comment: I meant is it possible to fix this? What I wrote above: If enter two or more spaces, then the problem comes back again.

Comment: It is possible to fix, yes. The issue is if you modify that line I don't know how you want to handle all the exceptions that creates.

Comment: I just meant that can somehow fix it, but the functionality of the macro remains the same: this macro converts the data to (any number)m and (any number)M on the right.

Comment: I know, but that line is fundamental to the functionality. I do not know how you want to handle the various paths that get opened up by modifying it. Remove the line and see what I mean, You'll get errors in some situations you'll lose data in others, it will format some things and not others. I simply don't have the information to tell you what to do here.